# Count occurance of a letter or a word in a sentence

Tags: javascript, for-loop, count, substring

I wonder how I can find how many characters, example `e`, in a text using a `for` loop and a increasing substring to go through the whole text.

This is what I got so far.

#### HTML:

```
<p id="paragraph"> this is the sentence, how many letters "e" can you find? How many "is" can you find</p>
<input type="text" id="text"/> <input type="button" value="search" onclick="search()"/>
<p id="howmany"></p>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
function search() {
  var letter = document.getElementById("text").value;
  var text = document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML; 
  var count = 0;
  var string = text.substring(0); 

  for(var i = 0; i < text.length, i++) {
    count++
  }
  document.getElementById("howmany").innerHTML = ("The result is" + count)
}
```

I only get how many characters there is in the text, but I want to find how many `e` or `is` or whatever there is in the text. I know there is something missing but what?

Comment: You really need to read up on javascript, there is no `getElementsById` or `innerHtml` etc. and there is no `clickOn`, there's basically an error on every single line of code you've written !

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a loop for this - you can just use a regex and count the matches:

```
string.match(/e/g).length
string.match(/is/g).length
```

That said, there are a bunch of other errors in your code:

```
function search() {
  var letter = document.getElementById("text").value;
  var text = document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML; 
  var count = 0;
  var string = text.substring(0,text.lenght); // should be length; or else not needed at all

  for(var i = 0; i < text.length, i++) {
    count++ 
  }
  document.getElementsById("howmany").innerHtml = ("The result is" + count) // it's getElementById, not getElements; it's innerHTML, not innerHtml
}
```

Also: `onclick`, on `clickOn`.

Answer (score 0):

My own take on this problem:

```js
function howMany () {
  var needle = document.getElementById('text').value.trim(),
      textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
      haystack = document.getElementById('paragraph')[textProp].trim(),
      result = haystack.match(new RegExp(needle, 'g'));
  document.getElementById('howmany')[textProp] = result ? result.length : 0;
}

document.querySelector('input[type=button]').addEventListener('click', howMany);
```

```css
#howmany::before {
  content: 'Matches found: ';
}

#howmany:empty::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">This is the sentence, how many letters "e" can you find? How many "is" can you find</p>
<label>String to find: <input id="text" placeholder="what are you looking for?" /></label>
<input type="button" value="search" />
<p id="howmany"></p>
```

References:

- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementById).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).
- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).